# Ionic 2 IOS push notification activation without using MAC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created IONIC 2 App and currently have launched only android version, now I am planning to publish IOS version for the same.

I created IOS package using ionic package and tested in Iphone and its working but the PUSH Notification is not working for IOS and I can not find a way to implement PUSH notification for IOS without using MAC/XCODE.

Docs explain things by using XCODE - https://docs.ionic.io/services/push

Please let me know what changes I need to make to activate PUSH for IOS, I already have created **APN Certificate** & **App Development/App Store Certificate** and have linked to IONIC.IO

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: How did you deploy the app to an iphone device without a mac ? Didn't think it was possible to package the app for ios on anything other than a mac.

Comment: Ionic package provides PACKAGE service that provides uploading your project to cloud and it will bundle ios build for you..

Comment: I see nice i don't see any xcode in the link you provided did you make it does mention "If you're using the latest version of Xcode, you will likely need to activate the Push Notifications capability before your app is able to receive notifications." Have you tried this ?